# React Hooks: Loading state displaying twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

##### I have an `isLoading` useState variable. In the code below purposefully commented out the `isLoading(false)` to force the Loading UI to test it. However I'm seeing it render twice, any idea why?

[image]

### API Call

```js
export default function App() { 
  const [upcoming, setUpcoming] = useState([]); 
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUpcoming = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const res = await fetch(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key={API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1"
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      const results = data.results;

      setUpcoming(results);
      // setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchUpcoming();
  }, []);

return (
    <div className="App">
      <Recommendations title={"Upcoming"} data={upcoming} loading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Render Results

```js
export default function Recommendations({ title, data, loading }) {
  return (
    <div className="recommendationSection">
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      {loading ? (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      ) : (
        data.map((movie) => {
          return (
            <div className="banner" key={movie.title}>
              <img
                src={
                  movie.poster_path
                    ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.poster_path}`
                    : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
                }
                alt={movie.title}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you share a codeSandbox link  with same issues ?  (code wise on a high level things are looking fine  to me)

Comment: hmmm, never created one before. i can try, not sure how much of the existing project i'll need to port over to make this work. it's a fairly large project.

Comment: figured it out, since i'm using Slick Slider, i had to add `infinite: false`, found the answer here: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/940#issuecomment-181815974

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/940#issuecomment-181815974

I found the second instance had a class of `slick-cloned` and basically since i'm using Slick Slider, it's making a clone of my element. The fix is to add `infinite: false` in my slider settings.